# Ads aren't displaying correctly in IE11

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising, browser-support

Unless Slack is trying some really covert recruitment tactics, there seems to be rendering issue with some ads in the sidebar:

[image: bad ad]

I've also seen ads where text doesn't wrap, and you only see half of a sentence where the logo is in the above ad.

I'm using IE11 at work (to my sorrow), which is apparently [still supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). I don't know this is a browser compatibility issue, just guessing.

Not sure whether responsibility for this lies with the ad-server or Stack Overflow or someone else, but thought it was worth flagging.

Comment: IE always has to do things a bit *differently*. Here, you’ve discovered that its ad blocker is implemented using the secret sauce of “massive incompatibility with web standards”. The other major browsers have been struggling to copy this feature for years.

Comment: @CodyGray s̶t̶r̶u̶g̶g̶l̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶p̶y̶  successfully avoiding

Comment: Chrome does a passable job of creatively interpreting the standards and creating breakage. Still a way to go, but good progress is being made on that front.

Comment: Finally! A way to reward IE users for all their hard effort.

Comment: [There's a relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/111/). Explains his work's reluctance to change browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with the ads team here at Stack Overflow. Thank you for bringing this to our attention! It turns out this was a specific issue occurring only for users of IE11. We have worked with the advertising partner to correct the issue, and you should no longer be having an issue regarding this particular ad.

Best,

Will